# Method overloading is not working while using superclass reference

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
class Communication {
    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Greetings..");
    }

    public void greet(String custom) {
        System.out.println(custom);
    }
}

public class Human extends Communication {
    public void greet(int n) { //overloading
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            System.out.println(i + " Hey..");
    }

    public void greet(String name) { //overriding
        System.out.println("Hi " + name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Communication communication = new Communication();
        communication.greet();
        communication.greet("Hello World");

        Communication humanCommunication = new Human();
        // humanCommunication.greet(2); is not working why?
        humanCommunication.greet("Sagar");

        Human human = new Human();
        human.greet();
        human.greet(2);

    }

}
```

Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method greet(String) in the type Communication is not applicable for the arguments (int).

I have overloaded the method in Human class and able to invoke while using Human object directly
but while assigning Human object to Communication reference Overridden method is working properly
and Overloading is not supporting Why?
Can any body help me to understand this behaviour? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `Communication` know about its subclasses?

Comment: `Communication` does not have a method `greet(int)`, so is `humanCommunication` suppose to be able to call it?

Comment: But I am assigning Human object to it Which is having
    public void greet(int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            System.out.println(i + " Hey..");
    }

  Communication humanCommunication = new Human();

@MadProgrammer

Comment: BUT `humanCommunication` is declared as a type of `Communication`, it's a wolf in sheeps clothing, `humanCommunication` is an instance of `Human` BEHAVING like an instance of `Communication`, so it can't call `greet(int)` as `Communication` doesn't declare it...

Comment: You could, however use `((Human)humanCommunication).greet(2)` ;)

Comment: ((Human)humanCommunication).greet(2); is working.
But why it is happening even still it is not declared in Communication
What does this casting means?
Can you elaborate this please.. @MadProgrammer

Comment: `humanCommunication` is declared as `Communication`, so it can only ever behave that way, but because `Human` is extended from `Communication`, it can "act" as an instance `Communication`.  But when acting as a `Communication` instance, it can only access the methods and properties that are declared by `Communication`, by casting, `humanCommunication` to `Human`, we unmask it for what it really is.  You can't, however case `communication` to `Human`, as `communication` is only ever an instance of `Communication`

Comment: without unmasking, Overridden method is working fine.
But Overloaded method is not working why like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler has no way of knowing which run time object will be assigned to a reference.
For example you could re-write your above code as,

```
boolean creatHuman = true;
Communication humanCommunication;
if(createHuman)
  humanCommunication = new Human();
else 
  humanCommunication = new Communication ();
```

The compiler can only tell for certain that humanCommunication will be of type Communication and so allows only methods available in type Communication

If you need to use methods available in Human you would need to tell the compiler that the Reference is a Human 
Two ways you could do it,

1. Declare humanCommunication as type Human
2. Cast during the call to the method available only in Human (). In case the dynamic type of the reference humanCommunication is not Human a CastClassException will be thrown

   ((Human) humanCommunication).greet(2); --> should work

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer as my friend said that this is the difference between Compile-time polymorphism vs run-time polymorphism
1)Method overloading is a compile time Polymorphism.
[Reference type determines which overloaded version (based
on declared argument types) is selected. Happens at compile
time. The actual method that’s invoked is still a virtual method
invocation that happens at runtime, but the compiler will
already know the signature of the method to be invoked. So at
runtime, the argument match will already have been nailed
down, just not the class in which the method lives.]
2)Method overriding is a run time Polymorphism.
[Object type (in other
words, the type of the
actual instance on the
heap) determines which
method is selected.
Happens at runtime.]
Thank you for comments :)